# Twitter Search API - Over 20 terms

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-search

I am attempting to pull several @user and #hashtags from the twitter search API. The complexity of the query is causing a 403 error. Wondering what the recommended work around for this is.

My thought is to query each term individually. So if I have 40 @users I want to get tweets for, I will make 40 queries, cache each, and then pull the data from the cache and display as one feed.

If there is an alternative method or suggestion, I would greatly appreciate any insight.

Comment: Is it possible to have an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Twitter tweaks their search complexity algorithm and the exact details may change over time. I believe the rule-of-thumb in logical operations is about 10. To translate, each term is an OR operation. So, you might be okay with 10 terms per query and might want to experiment to see how many you can do to avoid the 403 and then back-off to give more room in case the complexity score on your query changes.

Joe